# Restarting Supervisor after Nimbus fails

Tags: apache-storm

If my Nimbus fails and after that a Supervisor fails, who can restart the Supervisor again? Can the client do that / can I do that manually? Or should I instead restart the (or a) Nimbus manually and that restarts the Supervisor again?

Answer (score 1):

If Nimbus or Supervisor fails, you need to restart each of them manually (even in Nimbus is running, it will not restart a Supervisor). Of course, you can also automate this by using external tools like containers or a framework like YARN.

Of both fail at the same time, you need to restart Nimbus first. (For a Supervisor restart, you need a running Nimbus, as Supervisor tries to connect to Nimbus on start-up.)

Comment: I learned that if a Worker Process fails, the respective Supervisor would restart it. If a Supervisor fails, Nimbus restarts it. If a Worker Node fails, its processes are restarted by Nimbus on a different node. Is that wrong?

Comment: Workers get restarted by Supervisors. Everything else works as described in my answer. (where did you get those information?)

Comment: If a supervisor fails, Nimbus reassign the work to other supervisor (I guess, that is what you mean by "worker node fails"). Those supervisor start new worker process for this case (ie, Nimbus does not restart any processes -- however it triggers supervisors to start new workers).

Comment: When talking about "Worker Node" I mean the (more or less) physical node - could be a virtual machine though (thus "more or less"). If a Worker Node fails (e.g. machine blows up), the responsible Supervisor would not be available anymore (true), nor would be any of the Worker Node's Worker Processes. However, the Supervisor might be unavailable for other reasons than the entire Worker Node being gone, leaving the Worker Processes available.

Comment: So are you saying that if a Supervisor fails, all Worker Processes on this Supervisor's node die as well? What if the Supervisor dies, but the physical node it is responsible for (it's Worker Node) is still fine?

Comment: If only supervisor JVM dies and worker JVM are actually fine, I am not 100% sure what happens with worker JVMs. AFAIK, they will be "decoupled" from the other workers, as their share of the work should get assigned to a different supervisor that starts up new workers taking over the work (thus, to avoid duplicates etc. open worker JVM network connection will be closed by connected remote workers). Not sure if worker JVM dies or just run as kinda "zombie" workers.